# I keep getting MySql error while executing mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

My simple PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT 'food', 'calories' FROM 'food'";

    if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
        echo 'Query success';
    }else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
```

My error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''food'' at line 1

Can't really find out the problem, please any help?

Comment: backticks (or nothing at all). Never single quotes for that at least. Backticks, upper left corner of keyboard. Use single quotes for strings or surrounding datetimes and the like.

Comment: [`mysql_` functions are deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should be using [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) functions or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). I recommend PDO because of (among other things) named placeholders for prepared statements. It makes query building and security easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT food, calories FROM food";

    if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
        echo 'Query success';
    }else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
```

Use above code.

Are you sure your table name is food, and you have columns by name food and calories.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to delete single quotes

$query = "SELECT food, calories FROM food";

```
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
    echo 'Query success';
}else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```